# playground-common package giving 'Failed to build scrypt-0.5.0' error

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, smart-contract, cabal

I'm trying to run my own little smart contract in the `plutus-pioneer-program` [fourth iteration] docker container and I'm having some problems. I've just added an extra folder alongside the other weeks. I've built this same code on other environments just fine but I got a new laptop with an M2 chip recently so my setup all broke and I figured running it in this environment would be the fastest way forward. I've narrowed the issue down to the `playground-common` package that my build depends on. The problem is that when I run `cabal build all` in my folder I get this error:

```
Build log (
/root/.cabal/logs/ghc-8.10.7/scrypt-0.5.0-833a2feabba78b918876049577f7c64bc2870cc56e8d7720fba2aa8ea196973a.log
):
Configuring library for scrypt-0.5.0..
cabal-3.6.2.0: Missing dependency on a foreign library:
* Missing (or bad) header file: crypto_scrypt.h
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
--extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.If the
library file does exist, it may contain errors that are caught by the C
compiler at the preprocessing stage. In this case you can re-run configure
with the verbosity flag -v3 to see the error messages.
If the header file does exist, it may contain errors that are caught by the C
compiler at the preprocessing stage. In this case you can re-run configure
with the verbosity flag -v3 to see the error messages.

cabal: Failed to build scrypt-0.5.0 (which is required by
elysium-contract-0.1.0.0). See the build log above for details.
```

I havent changed anything else in the project other than adding an additional folder under `code`. Has something changed with the `playground-common` package?

I also tried adding this configuration to a `cabal.project.local` file, but no luck:

```
flags: -scrypt
tests: False
benchmarks: False
optimization: 2
```

Using cabal version `3.4`, base `^>=4.14.1.3.0`
Other config:

```
                     , base ^>=4.14.1.3.0
                     , bytestring
                     , cardano-api
                     , containers
                     , data-default
                     , playground-common
                     , plutus-ledger-api
                     , plutus-tx-plugin
                     , plutus-tx
                     , serialise
                     , text
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  ghc-options:         -Wall -fobject-code -fno-ignore-interface-pragmas
                       -fno-omit-interface-pragmas -fno-strictness 
                       -fno-spec-constr -fno-specialise -fexpose-all-unfoldings
                       -fplugin-opt PlutusTx.Plugin:defer-errors
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a C header file. Specifically, the part of the error message:

```
* Missing (or bad) header file: crypto_scrypt.h
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags.
```

On Debian based Linux systems (eg Debian, Ubuntu, Mint and probably others),
you can used `apt-file` to find which packages provides the file:

```
> apt-file search crypto_scrypt.h
libnode-dev: /usr/include/nodejs/src/crypto/crypto_scrypt.h
```

so that installing the `libnode-dev` package (part of `nodejs`):

```
sudo apt install libnode-dev
```

will sort your problems out.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply! When i run `apt-file search crypto_scrypt.h` nothing comes back, and installing `libnode-dev` didnt change the error message unfortunately :(

Comment: Are you on Debian or a Debian derived system? If so, which one?

Comment: My machine is a mac with m2 chip, but cabal is running in docker and this is the info about the image:
`cat /etc/os-release`
```NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.5 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
```

Comment: If you are running in docker supposedly its supposed to act just like Ubuntu on `x86-64` . Maybe you need to add the `universe` and `multiverse` repos for Ubuntu.

Comment: Just checked, they're both already enabled :/

Comment: The Ubuntu version you are using is from 2020 (`VERSION="20.04.5 LTS (Focal Fossa)"`), Maybe try the most recent LTS version which should be `22.???`.

Comment: hey I upgraded to 22.04 and now a whole bunch of other packages are broken/cant be found too and the scrypt error remains the same.. im wondering if i should try running cabal a different way >.< this is crazy complicated

Comment: Which packages? Haskell packages or others?

Comment: Here are the new errors:

<no location info>: error:
    Warning: Couldn't figure out LLVM version!
             Make sure you have installed LLVM between [9 and 13)
ghc: could not execute: opt-10
cabal: Failed to build scrypt-0.5.0 (which is required by
elysium-contract-0.1.0.0)
Failed to build streaming-commons-0.2.2.1 (which is required by
elysium-contract-0.1.0.0)
Failed to build x509-store-1.6.7 (which is required by
elysium-contract-0.1.0.0)
Failed to build zlib-bindings-0.1.1.5 (which is required by
elysium-contract-0.1.0.0)

Comment: > opt --version
Ubuntu LLVM version 14.0.0
  
  Optimized build.
  Default target: aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  Host CPU: (unknown)

Comment: If these are non-Haskell packages (ie LLVM) this is an Ubuntu problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue with setting up the environment on aarch64 M1 Mac, even within a Ubuntu VM on the same chip. The scrypt component fails due to its current support being limited to x86. More details can be found in this GitHub issue. https://github.com/informatikr/scrypt/issues/8

The best way around it is either a x86 machine or an x86 VM. I have setup mine as remote server. Life is easier this way

If someone did want to try to build it on a aarch64 I would recommend somehow making the build use this fork https://github.com/SupercedeTech/scrypt which is compatible